# Cannot apply operator / to operands struct and double

Tags: c#

I have a problem with a following line of code:

```
public Vector3 Normalized
{ get { return this / this.Length; } }
```

I get an error:

> "Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type Vector3 and
>   double"

Why am I getting this error?

Here's whole struct for reference:

```
struct Vector3
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;

    public Vector3(double x, double y, double z)
        : this()
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public double X
    { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }

    public double Y
    { get { return y; } set { y = value; } }

    public double Z
    { get { return z; } set { z = value; } }

    public static Vector3 operator +(Vector3 vecA, Vector3 vecB)
    {
        return new Vector3(vecA.X + vecB.X, vecA.Y + vecB.Y, vecA.Z + vecB.Z);
    }

    public static Vector3 operator -(Vector3 vecA, Vector3 vecB)
    {
        return new Vector3(vecA.X - vecB.X, vecA.Y - vecB.Y, vecA.Z - vecB.Z);
    }

    public static Vector3 operator *(Vector3 vecA, Vector3 vecB)
    {
        return new Vector3(vecA.X * vecB.X, vecA.Y * vecB.Y, vecA.Z * vecB.Z);
    }

    public static Vector3 operator /(Vector3 vecA, Vector3 vecB)
    {
        return new Vector3(vecA.X / vecB.X, vecA.Y / vecB.Y, vecA.Z / vecB.Z);
    }

    public double Dot(Vector3 vec)
    {
        return (this.X * vec.X + this.Y * vec.Y + this.Z * vec.Z);
    }

    public static Vector3 Cross(Vector3 vecA, Vector3 vecB)
    {
        return new Vector3(vecA.Y * vecB.Z - vecA.Z * vecB.Y,
            vecA.Z * vecB.X - vecA.X * vecB.Z,
            vecA.X * vecB.Y - vecA.Y * vecB.X);
    }

    public double Length
    { get { return Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z); } }

    public double LengthSq
    { get { return X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z; } }

    public Vector3 Normalized
    { get { return this / this.Length; } }
}
```

Comment: Well look at the `/` operator you've overloaded - look at its operands...

Comment: Ok, trying to write 10 classes in a hurry will give poor thinking, thank you.

Comment: The compiler error should have given you a clue :) Whenever the compiler says "I can't do that!" check that you've actually got code to do what you want it to do...

Comment: I'd also strongly advise against both mutable structs and public fields.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The struct doesn't have an operator that divides `Vector3` by `double`. It should look like this:

```
public static Vector3 operator /(Vector3 vecA, double scalar)
{
    return new Vector3(vecA.X / scalar, vecA.Y / scalar, vecA.Z / scalar);
}
```

Comment: probably should change the `*` operator as well.

Comment: Yes, thank you, copypasting in a hurry from operators +-. Simple mistake hardest to see.